# Transform Origin not Working even when set - CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am running a CSS transition to scale out box and I want to the scale to happen from the middle out but when setting the transform-origin nothing is happening. The transition always occurs from the top left. I have tried setting it in %'s, pxs , em, rems, and nothing no changes in chrome,firefox or IE.

The example is live here - http://codepen.io/Vince_Brown/pen/emJoga?editors=010

and you can trigger the transition I am referring to by clicking any of the add resource icons.

## HTML

```
<li class="resource--add">
    <h1 class="resource--add__title">Add Article</h1>
      <div class="resource__add-icon">
      <svg class="add" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
        <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="44.677,27.404 44.677,33.404 32.677,33.404 32.677,45.404 26.677,45.404 26.677,33.404 14.677,33.404 14.677,27.404 26.677,27.404 26.677,15.404 32.677,15.404 32.677,27.404 "/>
      </svg>

    </div>
      <p class="resource--add__summary">C'Mon and contribute you know you want to</p>
       <div class="resource--add__card"></div>
    </li>
```

## CSS(SCSS)

```
.resource--add{
  @extend %resource;
  svg {
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  // .resource--add__title
  @include e('title') {
    @extend .resource__title;
    text-align: center;
  }
  // .resource--add__summary
  @include e('summary') {
    @extend .resource__summary;
    text-align: center;
  }
  // .resource--add__card
  @include e('card') {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:6px 6px 12px rgba(palette(gray,light),.4),-6px -6px 12px rgba(palette(gray,light),.4);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    transform-origin: bottom,center;
  }

}
.card-is-active{
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  opacity:1;
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  transform-origin: bottom,center;
}
```

## JS

```
$('.resource__add-icon').on("click",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('icon-is-rotated');
  $(this).siblings('.resource--add__card').toggleClass('card-is-active');
});
```

Thanks in advance for the Help

## Cheers.

Comment: `transform-origin` values are not comma separated. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: @Paulie_D I left those in there by mistake. I have tried with and without commas . Without commas does not work either.